# Excel Formula for Printing Duplicates in New Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a sheet with three columns (A = date, B = phone number and C = direction) like below:

```
1/10/2011 11:00:05 AM    555-555-1212    Outbound
1/12/2011 01:00:45 AM    555-555-1212    Outbound
1/14/2012 06:58:22 PM    444-444-2323    Outbound
```

There are duplicate phone numbers in the sheet and I know how to find those.  What I need to have happen is anytime there is a duplicate, print all three columns of the duplicates in the columns to the right in the row of the first find.  So it would end up looking like this.

```
1/10/2011 11:00:05 AM    555-555-1212    Outbound     1/12/2011 01:00:45 AM  555-555-1212        Outbound
1/14/2012 06:58:22 PM    444-444-2323    Outbound
```

There may be 3 or four duplicates so those all would need to be printed to the right.  I would like to accomplish this with a formula but can't seem to be able to write one to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The current data setup is ideal for Excel.  Formulas like countif/s, sumif/s, conditional formatting, filtering, etc all rely on your current data setup.  I can see no reason you would want to change it to something significantly more difficult to work with

Comment: I have another sheet that has user data and phone numbers.  I need to match this call data with the user data.  So I planned on sorting the user data phone numbers smallest to largest and then doing the same with the call data and matching them up.  The problem is there are duplicates in the call data.  I also need to know every instance of call data that occurred for each user.  That's why if I can get the duplicates to the right, I can then just match up all of the call data numbers to the user data numbers.

Comment: Otherwise, I would need there to be blank rows inserted somehow under the user data every time there is a duplicate of the call data containing the duplicate call data.

Comment: Instead of changing the layout of your call data, use formulas to get what you need.  You can get a count of total calls on a phone number with countif, and a count of outbound/inbound for a phone number with countifs (or sumproduct if you're using Excel 2003 or lower).  I would still advocate keeping your call data layout.

Comment: I need to have the date and time of each call printed next to the user data of that number.  That is the issue.  If I didn't need to do that, I would not be asking this question.

Comment: The user data and call data came from two completely separate sources.

Comment: Excel can do that, but it would be resource intensive.  You should be using an actual database program, like Access or Oracle if handy.  Then you could just query the data for the results you want.  If it absolutely has to be in Excel, see this tutorial I wrote which should be of help to you http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/947848-lookup-a-value-and-return-multiple-results.html?p=3367753#post3367753

Comment: Note that the formula provided there will work fine for small data sets, but will probably slow Excel down for larger datasets.

Comment: I feel I should also add that most of the tutorial is for getting the results vertically, but towards the bottom, and in the sample file, it shows how to get the results horizontally

Comment: I will check out your link.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: if you need to display both user and call data in 1 place with the granularity of call data, you should append user info to call table, not vice versa - e.g. using [`=index(.., match(.., .., 0))`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/dynamic-searching-using-vlookup-match-and-index-HA001154902.aspx)